# MySQL SImple Joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to MySQL and trying to figure out how best to handle joins when you have 2 foreign key point to a primary key in a different table.

So basically, the first table contains a gameID (PK) and two player ID (FK)

```
-----------+------------+------------+
| Game_ID  | Player1_ID | Player2_ID |
+----------+------------+------------+
| 45897    | 569878D    | 458998E    |
| 56984    | 789878S    | 559845S    |
| 56984    | 389845S    | 8998784    |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

The Second table holds the Player Details, Player_ID is the PK key here

```
-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| Player_ID  | First_Name | Second_Name | Expert_Level | 
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 569878D    | John       | Ryan        | Novice       |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 458998E    | James      | Matthew     | Expert       |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 789878S    | Nicole     | Martin      | Casual       |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 559845S    | Tim        | Farage      | Casual       |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 389845S    | Gerard     | Williams    | Novice       |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 8998784    | Thompson   | Page        | Novice       |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

How would I go about joining the two table, to get as an example where players are in a game with the wrong skill level. In this case something like below, since one is a Novice and the second is an expert

```
-----------+------------+------------+
| Game_ID  | Player1_ID | Player2_ID |
+----------+------------+------------+
| 45897    | 569878D    | 458998E    |
-----------+------------+------------+
```

I have been trying something like this.. but can't seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT Game_Table.Player1_ID AS "Player1", Game_Table.Player2_ID AS "Player2",     Player_Table.Expert_Level
FROM Game_Table, Game_Table 
WHERE Player1.Expert_Level != Player2.Expert_Level
```

Comment: List person table twice with different table aliases and join it 1 time each to playeer1 and player2_id.

Comment: What the heck is nationality I don't see that listed.

Comment: Sorry, that is copy and paste for another else I was working on.. got it fixed now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok your copy and paste skills and mixing of two different questions is killing me.... but this is what I think you're after...

Fundamentally anytime you have a multiple fk's back to the same table that are not composite keys, then you need additional joins with table aliases.

```
SELECT PD.Player_ID as `Person1`
     , PD.Player_ID as `Person2`
     , PT1.Expert_level as `Person1 Expert_Level`
     , PT2.Expert_level as `Person2 Expert Level`
FROM Player_Details PD
LEFT JOIN Person_Table p1
 on P1.PlayerID = PD.Player1_ID
LEFT JOIN Person_Table P2
 on P2.PlayerID = PD.Player2_ID
WHERE P1.Expert_Level <> P2.Expert_level
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.Game_ID,
    b.Player_ID as `Player_1_ID`,
    b.First_Name as `Player_1_First_Name`,
    b.Last_Name as `Player_1_Last_Name`,
    b.Expert_Level as `Player_1_Expert_Level`,
    c.Player_ID as `Player_2_ID',
    c.First_Name as `Player_2_First_Name`,
    c.Last_Name as `Player_2_Last_Name`,
    c.Expert_Level as `Player_2_Expert_Level`
FROM `games` a
JOIN `players` b
ON a.Player1_ID = b.Player_ID
JOIN `players` c
ON a.Player1_ID = c.Player_ID
WHERE b.Expert_Level <> c.Expert_Level
```

It should list all games where the Expert_Level of the two players doesn't match.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what i am looking for.. now to understand this complex code :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    g.Player1_ID AS "Player1",
    p1.Expert_Level AS "Player1_Expert_Level",
    g.Player2_ID AS "Player2",     
    p2.Expert_Level AS "Player2_Expert_Level",
FROM Game_Table g
    INNER JOIN Player_Table p1 ON p1.Player_ID = g.Player1_ID
    INNER JOIN Player_Table p2 ON p2.Player_ID = g.Player2_ID 
WHERE p1.Expert_Level <> p2.Expert_Level;
```